# Apache server giving to much info

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-12.04

So I have been working on my web server for a good part of the day, and now I am getting done almost and for some reason no matter where I put :

- ServerTokens Prod
- ServerSignature Off

in the apache.conf or in the httpd.conf files

And to still no avail. I tried putting into sites-available and still nothing. Am I doing something wrong here?

my modules enabled go like so :

1. Mod_Alias
2. Mod_authz_host
3. mod_deflate
4. Mod_mime
5. Mod_php5
6. Mod_reqtimeout
7. Mod_setenvif
8. mod_ssl

Am I missing anything to this?

-Thanks.

Comment: Are you restarting apache after your configuration changes?

Comment: I literally just found out why this was happening. You must go to /conf.d/security then you can find the two variables there. However all other "security hardening sites" / tutorials tell you to put it in httpd

Comment: Great! Please post that as an answer and then come back in a day or two to accept your own answer.

Comment: New users only need to wait 8 hours before accepting their own answer. So not that long.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the wait I had to wait to input the answer but here it is :

go to /etc/apache2/conf.d/security and there you will see the two variables. Spread the word as all the "how to sites" stated to put the ServerTokens and ServerSignature on apache2.conf and that didn't work. And for noobies (like me) this is very misleading.